# How do i take User Input from Keyboard in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, calculator, visual-c++-2010

I am using Visual C++ 2010 to make my very first project - A Calculator(Following an online tutorial).

Now, the calculator is done and functioning, however, the only way to input the numbers is by pressing the buttons with a mouse.

I want to be able to do so with my keyboard. How can I do it?

```
    double iFirstNumber;
    double iSecondNumber;
    double iResult;
    String^ iOperator;

private: System::Void btnC_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         //button C
         txtDisplay->Text="0";
         lblShowOp->Text ="";
     }
private: System::Void btnCE_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         //button CE
         txtDisplay->Text="0";
     }
private: System::Void button_click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         //Numeric Buttons
         Button ^ Numbers = safe_cast<Button^>(sender);

         if(txtDisplay->Text =="0")
         {
            txtDisplay->Text = Numbers->Text ;
         }

         else
         {
            txtDisplay->Text = txtDisplay->Text + Numbers->Text;
         }
     }

private: System::Void button14_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         //Equals
         lblShowOp->Text = "";
         iSecondNumber = Double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);

         if(iOperator == "+")
         {
            iResult = iFirstNumber + iSecondNumber;
            txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(iResult);
         }

         else if(iOperator == "-")
         {
            iResult = iFirstNumber - iSecondNumber;
            txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(iResult);
         }

         else if(iOperator == "x")
         {
            iResult = iFirstNumber * iSecondNumber;
            txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(iResult);
         }

         else if(iOperator == "÷")
         {
            iResult = iFirstNumber / iSecondNumber;
            txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(iResult);
         }

         if(iOperator == "x²")
         {
            iResult = iFirstNumber * iFirstNumber;
            txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(iResult);
            lblShowOp->Text= System::Convert::ToString(iFirstNumber) + " " + "²";
         }
     }
private: System::Void btnBack_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         if(txtDisplay->Text->Length>0)
         {
             txtDisplay->Text = txtDisplay->Text->Remove(txtDisplay->Text->Length -1,1);
         }
     }
private: System::Void txtDisplay_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         if(txtDisplay->Text == "")
         {
            txtDisplay->Text = "0";
         }
     }
private: System::Void btnDot_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         if(!txtDisplay->Text->Contains("."))
         {
            txtDisplay->Text = txtDisplay->Text + ".";
         }
     }
private: System::Void btnPM_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         if(txtDisplay->Text->Contains("-"))
         {
            txtDisplay->Text->Remove(0,1);
         }


         if(!txtDisplay->Text->Contains("-"))
         {
            txtDisplay->Text = "-" + txtDisplay->Text;
         }

     }

private: System::Void operators2(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         Button ^ op = safe_cast<Button^>(sender);
         iFirstNumber = Double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);
         txtDisplay->Text ="";
         iOperator = op->Text;
         if(iOperator == "+" || iOperator == "-" || iOperator == "x" || iOperator == "÷")
         {
            lblShowOp->Text= System::Convert::ToString(iFirstNumber) + " " + iOperator;
         }
         else if(iOperator == "x²")
         {
            lblShowOp->Text = System::Convert::ToString(iFirstNumber) + " " + "²";
         }
     }

};
}
```

This is my code so far.

Answer (score -1):

By the code that you post, it seems that you're using C++/CLI and WinForms, then System::Windows::Forms::Form has a KeyDown event. Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx (inside the page, change to C++ language)

I hope that it help you.